# Connect Algolia with Odoo

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-9, algolia

Can anyone help me in configuring Algolia with odoo? I am using odoo search engine connectors. I have trouble in connecting with Algolia. Please help me.

Comment: can you elaborate the area where you are facing the issue. Also do share the logs

Comment: @SudhanshuGupta    I am getting the below error while exporting product to Algolia.
 
 File "C:\odoo\odoo-10\addons-extra\connector\backend.py", line 269, in get_class
    (base_class, session, model_name))
NoConnectorUnitError: No matching class found for <class 'odoo.addons.connector_nosql.unit.exporter.NosqlExporter'>

I think I have wrongly configured backend connector. I have given values for location field as algolia.com, username as my_app_id and password as secret_api_key. Is this theway to configure ?